# Unable to share text on Whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I am using following code to share text on WhatsApp from my iOS app.

```
        NSString *textToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", self.theTextView.text];
        NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:textToSend];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
        }else{
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Whatsapp not isntalled on this device! Please install first." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        }
```

This is not working as expected.

If I do like explained [here](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) it works fine.

```
        NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that **self.theTextView.text** is not getting URL-encoded.

How to solve that:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Assuming that you're using UTF8.

Comment: A URL cannot contain special characters (e.g. whitespace ' ' is converted to '%20'). You need to parse your text and replace those characters with valid ones.

Answer (score 8):

Matteo Pacini your answer is not correct,

you have to ADD PercentEscapes (`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`) NOT REPLACE PercentEscapes (`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`)

```
string = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```